# HashMap in an SQLite Database

Tags: java, sqlite

I would like to store a HashMap in an SQLite Database. I have tried using an object database, but it's more bulky than I would like for android development. Would I just serialize it and then store the result of serialization? Or must I do something else?

Comment: Just one map or multiple -- and if multiple, how many, etc? How will the data be accessed? There are a number of different ways this can go. I use a custom very compact binary serialization (albeit in .NET): I also have 10k+ maps (two per "item", each with 2-50+ keys) where almost all keys are duplicated. This is a far different requirement than just storing a single set of configuration settings, for instance.

Comment: Its just a single map, with three pairings of String --> ArrayList

Comment: Another approach is to just make a table where the columns are the keys in the map. This works well for a fixed object representation. If the map is "part" of another record, then serialization may make more sense. If it is just a store, then using the [Entity-attribute model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-attribute-value_model) may be appropriate (however, don't use EAV over a "wide" table if applicable!). Just don't get fixated on one approach -- choose one that fits the design.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seeing HashMap is a key/value pair, why not add all keys/values to a JSON Object and store the object in SQLite?

Comment: I thought that if I did this, when I retrieved it it would appear to the computer as a String. Is this not the case?

Comment: @providence JSON -is- a string serialization (well, text really). The various JSON libraries allow accessing the JSON as "an object graph" or converting it to/from a native object representation. See http://json.org :-)

Answer (score 1):

A Map is key/value pairs.  If you have a table with a primary key column that matches your Map key you can add one row per Map entry into the database.

Comment: Yes, this is possible, but I was inspired by the process by which ObjectOutputStream/ObjectInputStream work to think that perhaps by storing the byte output of the serialization process in a database, I could reconstruct the exact same object by de-serializing it later. Then I also thought that perhaps I misunderstood how something was working.. does this sound possible?

Comment: @providence: Possible but it goes against the grain of relational databases, like trying to use a cellphone display as a flashlight: you could do it in a pinch if you really had to (and I actually have) but there are tools that are a much better match for the job.